# Set the index of a dataframe as the columns and vice versa

Tags: python, pandas

How do I get the index of a dataframe set as the columns and vice versa? I tried unstacking it but in vain.

I want to turn this dataframe

```
       Type1    Type2   Type3
Hour                
0        5   0   13
1        3   5   5
2        3   2   11
3        9   3   8
4        1   3   2
5        0   0   2
6        1   5   0
7        0   1   0
8        2   0   0
9        1   0   1
10       0   0   2
11       6   2   2
12       5   3   1
13       3   4   2
14       4   2   4
15       10  3   6
16       7   1   6
17       18  1   5
18       6   2   6
19       2   4   27
20       10  8   16
21       19  12  36
22       5   9   11
23       8   8   23
```

to the following;

```
          0  1   2   3   4    5    6    7    8   9   10 ...
Type 1    5  3   3   9   1 ....
Type 2    0  5   2   3   3 ....
Type 3    13 5  11   8   2 ....
```

EDIT:
 I actually have a multi index in the original df which looks like `[(0, 1), (1, 1), (2, 1), (3, 1), (4, 1), (5, 1), (6, 1), (7, 1), (8, 1), (9, 1), (10, 1), (11, 1), (12, 1), (13, 1), (14, 1), (15, 1), (16, 1), (17, 1), (18, 1), (19, 1), (20, 1), (21, 1), (22, 1), (23, 1)]`. How do I handle that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Transpose the dataframe:

```
df.T
```

Does this do the trick?

Answer (score 1):

Call unstack twice:

```
In [47]:

df.unstack().unstack()

Out[47]:
       0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10  11  12  13  14  15  16  17  \
Type1   5   3   3   9   1   0   1   0   2   1   0   6   5   3   4  10   7  18   
Type2   0   5   2   3   3   0   5   1   0   0   0   2   3   4   2   3   1   1   
Type3  13   5  11   8   2   2   0   0   0   1   2   2   1   2   4   6   6   5   

       18  19      
Type1   6   2 ...  
Type2   2   4 ...  
Type3   6  27 ...  

[3 rows x 24 columns]
```

Also `.T` would work:

```
In [48]:

df.T
Out[48]:
       0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10  11  12  13  14  15  16  17  \
Type1   5   3   3   9   1   0   1   0   2   1   0   6   5   3   4  10   7  18   
Type2   0   5   2   3   3   0   5   1   0   0   0   2   3   4   2   3   1   1   
Type3  13   5  11   8   2   2   0   0   0   1   2   2   1   2   4   6   6   5   

       18  19      
Type1   6   2 ...  
Type2   2   4 ...  
Type3   6  27 ...  

[3 rows x 24 columns]
```

Comment: Thanks. One more thing. I have a multi index in the original df which looks like `[(0, 1), (1, 1), (2, 1), (3, 1), (4, 1), (5, 1), (6, 1), (7, 1), (8, 1), (9, 1), (10, 1), (11, 1), (12, 1), (13, 1), (14, 1), (15, 1), (16, 1), (17, 1), (18, 1), (19, 1), (20, 1), (21, 1), (22, 1), (23, 1)]`. How do I handle that?

Comment: Calling `df.T` would work for that case rather than calling `unstack` twice and I think you cannot use `unstack` in the case of a multi-index